# How to upload multiple images in multipart using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipart, alamofireimage

I am stuck in uploading multiple images in multipart using Alamofire. Can any one help me?
Thanks in advance!!

For more details, I am using this code to create body part of images data:

```
func imageArrayToNSData(array: [UIImage],boundary:String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData()
    var i = 0;
    for image in array{
        let filename = "image\(i).jpg"
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.8);
        let mimetype = "image/jpeg"
        let key = "product_images"
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(data!)
        body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        i += 1
    }

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    return body
}
```

to upload I am using :

```
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, EDIT_PRODUCT_URL, headers: ["Accept": "application/json","Content-Type":"application/json"], multipartFormData: { (formData) in

        if productImages.count>0{
            let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
            let imageData = CommonClass.imageArrayToNSData(productImages,boundary: boundary)
            formData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "product_images", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

        for (key, value) in params {
            if value is [String]{
                let data = CommonClass.stringArrayToNSData(value as! [String])
                formData.appendBodyPart(data:data , name: key)
            }else if value is String{
                formData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
            }else if let v = value as? Bool{
                var bValue = v
                let d = NSData(bytes: &bValue, length: sizeof(Bool))
                formData.appendBodyPart(data: d, name: key)
            }
        }

    }) { (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            KVNProgress.showProgress(CGFloat(0), status:"0% Sent")
            upload.progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
                // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
                // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    let prg = Int((CGFloat(totalBytesWritten)*100)/CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
                    if prg == 100{
                        KVNProgress.showSuccessWithStatus("Created")
                    }
                    KVNProgress.updateStatus("\(prg)% Sent")
                    KVNProgress.updateProgress(CGFloat(Float(prg)/100.0), animated: true)
                }
            }
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                CommonClass.hideLoader()
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        print_debug("edit Product JSON is\n\(json)");  
                        completionBlock(json)
                    }else{
                        completionBlock(nil)
                    }
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print_debug(error.description)
                    showErrorWithMessage("Oops! Couldn't connect to server!")
                    completionBlock(nil)
                }
            }

        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

Can any one please let me suggest the way to upload multiple files in multipart using Alamofire?

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 3 and above**
Just append "[]" with image key identifier to treat it as array of images.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            // import image to request
            for imageData in imagesData {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "\(imageParamName)[]", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to: urlString,

            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I Hope it will be helpful for you:

**Using Swift 3x:** (I have uploaded four Photos in this snippet)

```
 //MARK: - upload multiple photos

    func uploadImagesAndData(params:[String : AnyObject]?,image1: UIImage,image2: UIImage,image3: UIImage,image4: UIImage,headers : [String : String]?, completionHandler:@escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

        let imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5)!
        let imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.5)!

        let imageData3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image3, 0.5)!

        let imageData4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image4, 0.5)!


        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                for (key, value) in params! {
                    if let data = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                        multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
                    }
                }

                multipartFormData.append(imageData1, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                multipartFormData.append(imageData2, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                multipartFormData.append(imageData3, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                multipartFormData.append(imageData4, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        },
            to: K_BASEURL + K_API_LOGINDATA, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload
                        .validate()
                        .responseJSON { response in
                            switch response.result {
                            case .success(let value):
                                print("responseObject: \(value)")
                            case .failure(let responseError):
                                print("responseError: \(responseError)")
                            }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("encodingError: \(encodingError)")
                }
        })
    }
```

Comment: "withName" parameter has to be different  for every new append. Otherwise they will just get overwritten.

Comment: No, "fileName" is responsible for that! and "withName" is to be a "file" because this is just to specify the type.

Comment: @AnuragSharma can you tell me the code if we have to send images in separate array?

Answer (score 1):

**1) To upload multiple image using Alamofire in Swift3**

```
typealias APICompletionHandler = (code:Int, error:NSError?, response:AnyObject?) -> Void

func uploadIMultipart(_ strApiName:String, param : NSDictionary?, data:Array<NSDictionary>, header:[String : String]?, completionHandler:@escaping APICompletionHandler)
    {
        let strURL : String = strApiName

        let apiURL = try! URLRequest(url: strURL, method: .post, headers: header)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            // code
            var i : Int = 0
            for dict:NSDictionary in data {
                let extention = dict["format"] as? String
                let strMimeType = dict["strMimeType"] as? String
                let nameofFile:String = (6.randomString as String)+"."+extention!
                if (dict["data"] as? Data != nil) {
                    multipartFormData.append(Foundation.Data(dict["data"] as! Data), withName: dict["key"] as! String, fileName: nameofFile , mimeType: strMimeType!)
                } else {
                    let strUrl = dict["data"] as! String
                    let fileURL : URL? = URL(string: strUrl)
                    multipartFormData.append(try! Foundation.Data(contentsOf: fileURL!), withName: dict["key"] as! String, fileName: nameofFile , mimeType: strMimeType!)

                }
                i += 1
            }

            for (key, value) in param! {
                multipartFormData.append((value as! NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key as! String)
            }

        }, with: apiURL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            // code
            switch result {

            case .success(let upload,_ ,_ ):
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        //Sucess
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)

                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                completionHandler(0, encodingError as NSError?, nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

**2) To call Function**

```
        let imageData : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgUserProfile.image!)! as NSData
        let imageData1 : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgUserProfile.image!)! as NSData

        let dict1: Dictionary = ["data":imageData,"key":"user_image", "format":"jpg", "strMimeType":"image/jpeg"] as [String : Any]
        let dict2: Dictionary = ["data":imageData1,"key":"image1", "format":"jpg", "strMimeType":"image/jpeg"] as [String : Any]
        let array: Array = [dict1,dict2]; //pass this image array

        self.uploadIMultipart(strAPI, param: dictParam as NSDictionary, data: array as Array<NSDictionary>, header: nil) { (code, error, response) in
            AppSingletonObj.stopLoading(inView: self.view)

            //API manager sucess or failure
            if code == 1 {
                let status = response?["success"]

                //API sucess or failure
                if(status as! Int == 1) {
                    print(response!)
                }
                else {
                    let errorMessage = response?["message"]
                    AppSingletonObj.showAlert(msg: errorMessage as! String)
                }
            }
            else {
                AppSingletonObj.showAlert(msg: "Some error occured! please try after sometime")
            }
        }
```

**3) Extension to create file name**

```
//MARK: CREATE RANDOM STRING of LENGTH
extension Int{
    var randomString : String {

        let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: self)

        for _ in 0 ..< self{
            let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
            randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.character(at: Int(rand)))
        }
        return randomString as String
    }
}
```

Comment: Extra parameters which will be pass in API.

Answer (score 0):

To upload multiple image you need to call this code in loop

```
let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
let imageData = CommonClass.imageArrayToNSData(productImages,boundary: boundary)
formData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "product_images", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

Comment: Let me check @Rajat, If it solve, I will surely do the else work :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2.
Here code is only for without any parameters.
If you need to pass extra parameters just go with **@Hardik Thakkar** code.

```
typealias APICompletionHandler = (code:Int, error:NSError?, response:AnyObject?) -> Void

@IBOutlet weak var thirdImage: UIImageView!
var fristImage:UIImage = UIImage()
var secondimage:UIImage = UIImage()

extension ViewController {

  func upload() {

    let imgData1 = fristImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
    let imgData2 = secondimage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
    let imgData3 = thirdImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)
    let headers = [
        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + "Your Token",
        "Content-type": "form-data",
    ]
    let dict1: Dictionary = ["data":imgData1 as Any,"key":"Here Your Body Key1", "format":"jpg", "strMimeType":"image/jpeg"] as [String : Any]
    let dict2: Dictionary = ["data":imgData2 as Any,"key":"Here Your Body Key2", "format":"jpg", "strMimeType":"image/jpeg"] as [String : Any]
    let dict3: Dictionary = ["data":imgData3 as Any,"key":"Here Your Body Key3", "format":"jpg", "strMimeType":"image/jpeg"] as [String : Any]
    let array: Array = [dict1, dict2, dict3]; //pass this image array

    self.uploadIMultipart("Here Your URL", data: array as Array<NSDictionary>, header: headers) { (code, error, response) in

          let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
          print("the resopnse code is : \(String(describing: httpResponse?.statusCode.description))")
    }
  }

  func uploadIMultipart(_ strApiName:String, data:Array<NSDictionary>, header:[String : String]?, completionHandler:@escaping APICompletionHandler) {

    let strURL : String = strApiName
    let apiURL = try! URLRequest(url: strURL, method: .post, headers: header)
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        // code
        var i : Int = 0
        for dict:NSDictionary in data {
            let extention = dict["format"] as? String
            let strMimeType = dict["strMimeType"] as? String
            let nameofFile:String = (6.randomString as String)+"."+extention!
            if (dict["data"] as? Data != nil) {
                multipartFormData.append(Foundation.Data(dict["data"] as! Data), withName: dict["key"] as! String, fileName: nameofFile , mimeType: strMimeType!)
            } else {
                let strUrl = dict["data"] as! String
                let fileURL : URL? = URL(string: strUrl)
                multipartFormData.append(try! Foundation.Data(contentsOf: fileURL!), withName: dict["key"] as! String, fileName: nameofFile , mimeType: strMimeType!)    
            }
            i += 1
        }
    }, with: apiURL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
        // code
        switch result {

        case .success(let upload,_ ,_ ):

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let response):
                    //Sucess
                    print("response :-", response)
                case .failure(let error):
                    //Failure
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
            completionHandler(0, encodingError as NSError?, nil)
        }
    })
    }
}

extension Int{

    var randomString : String {

        let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: self)

        for _ in 0 ..< self{
            let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
            randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.character(at: Int(rand)))
        }
        return randomString as String
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class func uploadImageToServer(uploadTo: String, imageParameters:[[String: Any]], otherParameters:[String: Any],authorization: String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ responseValue: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

        if isNetWorkAvailable() {

            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: uploadTo)!)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            urlRequest.addValue(authorization, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                ActivityIndicatorView.showActivity()
            })
           print("Request Url: \(uploadTo)\nRequest Params: \(imageParameters)\nRequest Params: \(otherParameters)")
            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

                for (key,value) in otherParameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }

                for value  in imageParameters {
                    let image = value["image"] as! UIImage
                    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!
                    let imageName = value["imageName"] as! String
                    let fileName = value["fileName"] as! String

                    multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: imageName, fileName: fileName ,mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
            }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), with: urlRequest, encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) in
                switch encodingResult {

                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                        let uploadPercetange = Int(progress.fractionCompleted*100)
                        print("Upload Progress: \(uploadPercetange)%")
                    })
                    upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                        print(response.result.value ?? "NaN")
                        let result = response.result.value
                        completionHandler(result, nil)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            ActivityIndicatorView.hideActivity()
                        })
                    })

                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                    let error = encodingError
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        ActivityIndicatorView.hideActivity()
                    })
                }
            })
        } else {
            AlertView.showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Network not available")
        }

    }
```