# Multiple file upload with array of parameters using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, image-uploading

i have array of parameters and array of images each set of parameter contain one and only one image.my code

```
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 0.2)!
  Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

      for (key, value) in params {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
      }
    },
                   to:URLUpdateProfile,
                   method:.post,
                   headers:headers)
    { (result) in
      switch result {
      case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
          print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
          print(response.result.value)
        }

      case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)  
      }
    }
```

with this code i am able to upload one image along with one parameter.but i want to send parameter in array and image in array too.is the way to upload array of params with array of image? if yes how to track image and parameter?

Comment: Check here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262201/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-multipart-using-alamofire

Answer (score 1):

You can upload each image and its param in an `Operation`. Your `Operation` should look something like this:

```
class UploadImageOperation: Operation {
private var image: UIImage

init(withImage: UIImage) {
    super.init()

    image = withImage
}

override func main() {
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)!
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

        for (key, value) in params {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    },
                     to:URLUpdateProfile,
                     method:.post,
                     headers:headers)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result.value)
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you create the operations and add them to the queue like this:

```
let opQueue = OperationQueue()
opQueue.name = "imageUploadQueue"
opQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5 //number of images you want to be uploaded simultaneously
opQueue.qualityOfService = .background

for image in arrayOfImages {
    let uploadImageOperation = UploadImageOperation(withImage: image)
    opQueue.addOperation(uploadImageOperation)
}
```

Comment: how about param each image has its own param.and want to send them in array.

Comment: @PrashantGhimire you can do it the same way.

Comment: can you please provide me example for params too. actually i am stuck at this point.my problem is that i have have params and thats in array too ie   let params :Parameters = ["id" :[]),
                                  "name":[""],
                                  "dob":[""]]].and i am not able to do this         for (key, value) in params {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
it get crash because our value is not string its array of data.

Comment: @PrashantGhimire I believe you should create a separate question for that. It's another issue. I'll be glad to help you there.

Comment: please check my question i have ask that too.array of params and image