# Alamofire Image upload with Parameters and AuthToken Header with patch method

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, image-uploading

Here the alamofire code i am using

**params** is a dictionary `[String:Any]`

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

        for (key, value) in params {
            if let image = value as? UIImage {
                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2) {
                    MultipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                }
            }else {
                MultipartFormData.append(String(describing: value).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }

}, to:url, method: .patch, headers: ["token": authToken,"Content-Type":"application/json"]) { (result) in

    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                print(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error while requesting")
                return
            }
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
            }
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)
    }
}
```

I want to upload an image to the server, read some post for uploading via alamofire but none seems to be working for me?
Please help me find the issue here.

Solutions given in the duplicate question arent working for me

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload image to server using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire)

Comment: yea...tried but nothing works...do u think maybe server has the issue, cause i have tried everything that i hve encountered

Comment: what is this... method: .patch i didn't know much about this..

Comment: check out this link i given details answer in this link with (method: .post) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262201/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-multipart-using-alamofire/43634314#43634314.

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is wrong. Use
"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"

Comment: why you use patch method? Can you try post?

Comment: api developer has set it to patch :(